# How can I simplify the output after integration which is obtained in terms of hypergeometric function in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

When I did the integration of the following function, I got the answer in terms of hypergeometric function. But when I did the same integration in MATLAB, a simplified form of expression is coming as the answer (Please see the attached images).

**How can I simplify the output from Mathematica?**

```
r1 = ((x^2) + (R - y)^2)^(0.5);
r2 = ((x^2) + (R + y)^2)^(0.5);
P = ((R - y) x^2/r1^4);
U = Integrate[P, x]
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use 1/2 instead of 0.5 and apply FullSimplify after the integration.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: Hi @ShinsKarthikeyan, Welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour] so you understand what is expected on this site and earn your first badge! Here it’s considered helpful to share your code in a **[well-formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This [question in Meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-i-include-code-samples-in-posts) could be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use exact rational powers.

```
r1 = ((x^2) + (R - y)^2)^(1/2);
r2 = ((x^2) + (R + y)^2)^(1/2);
P = ((R - y) x^2/r1^4);
U = Integrate[P, x]
```

$$(R-y) \left(\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{R-y}\right)}{2 (R-y)}-\frac{x}{2 \left(R^2-2 R y+x^2+y^2\right)}\right)$$

---

**EDIT**

Or use `Rationalize` later.

```
r1 = ((x^2) + (R - y)^2)^0.5;
r2 = ((x^2) + (R + y)^2)^0.5;
P = ((R - y) x^2/r1^4);
U = Integrate[P, x] // Rationalize // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x (y-R)}{(R-y)^2+x^2}+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{R-y}\right)\right)$$

Comment: The problem is solved now. Thank you so much for the responses. Thank you @rhermans for your suggestion. I will do the needful when I post something next time.

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.